# string format for printf floating point values

Tags: c, string, printf, string-formatting, floating-point-conversion

I have a question about using printf.

```
char str[8];
float val = 2.334563;
sprintf(str, format, val);
printf("val = %s.\n", str);

val = -23.34563;
sprintf(str, format, val);
printf("val = %s.\n", str);

val = -0.02334563;
sprintf(str, format, val);
printf("val = %s.\n", str);

val = 233;
sprintf(str, format, val);
printf("val = %s.\n", str);
```

The expected output follows:

```
val = +2.3345
val = -23.345
val = -0.0233
val = +233.00
```

What format string do I need for that? Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 3):

what happened to the good old `%f`

Comment: Does not get desired output. His question should of asked more directly.

Comment: @JoeMcGrath: This Q clearly smells of Homework & I do not appreciate writing any form of code for Homework Questions other than giving pointers or ideas. **Reason:** I do not want an programmer sitting right beside me(Albeit a few yrs from now) who cannot write a source code given a hint.

Comment: Ok thanks. I am new to Stack Overflow and did not realize. Just trying to answer questions.  I am a hobbyist programmer who hasn't been to school.  Did not think of homework assignments.  Will remember to do this in future.

Comment: @JoeMcGrath: Yes,please.I understand your enthusiasm and willingness to help but We do not really want to turn SO in to a **Do My Homework** Website.Usually,for Q's which smell of homework We would like to see what the OP has tried,their efforts and their ideas to solve the problem.Then provide subtle hints/clues which will give them a direction and unblock them but also leaves them enough sizeable homework to do.As a hobbyist programmer you would sure know,there is no alternative to hard work.Welcome to SO and See you around.All the Best :)

Answer (score 1):

```
"%f"
```

example

```
printf("%f\n", floatVal);
```

Comment: I need fixed size output string.

Comment: nor will `"%f"` show the + sign in front of positive numbers.

Answer (score 1):

use `snprintf()` to truncate string at exactly 8 characters including `\0`

Format string:

```
"%#+.5f"

%   modifier
#   force decimal place
+   show + or -
.5  precision of 5
f   use precision as places after decimal
```

Code:

```
char str[8];
float val = 2.334563;
snprintf(str,8, "%#+.5f", val);
printf("val = %s\n", str);

val = -23.34563;
snprintf(str,8, "%#+.5f", val);
printf("val = %s\n", str);

val = -0.02334563;
snprintf(str,8, "%#+.5f", val);
printf("val = %s\n", str);

val = 233.001;
snprintf(str,8, "%#+.5f", val);
printf("val = %s\n", str);
```

Output:

```
val = +2.3345
val = -23.345
val = -0.0233
val = +233.00
val = +0.0003
```

Comment: I think snprintf(str, 8, "%#+.5f", 0.0003); best of all

Comment: @user1020803 That does work in all cases. Got lost in all my changes not sure why i was still using sig figs after i switched to snprintf().  Thanks. edited to reflect.

Answer (score 1):

The following (almost) does what you want. Note that I changed the number of characters in the `str` array from 7 to 8; since all of your output strings contain 7 characters the NULL termination performed by `sprintf` will cause buffer overflow otherwise.

The only difference between my results and yours is the rounding performed by `sprintf`. AFAIK, the only way to get around this is to pre-truncate the number you want to print using `floor`; for example, to print 2 digits without rounding `float f = floor( 1.8888 * 100 ) / 100;`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char str[8];

  {
    float val = 2.334563f;
    sprintf(str, "%+6.*f", 4, val);
    printf("val = %s.\n", str);
  }

  {
    float val = -23.34563f;
    sprintf(str, "%+6.*f", 3, val);
    printf("val = %s.\n", str);
  }

  {
    float val = -0.02334563f;
    sprintf(str, "%+6.*f", 4, val);
    printf("val = %s.\n", str);
  }

  {
    float val = 233.0f;
    sprintf(str, "%+6.*f", 2, val);
    printf("val = %s.\n", str);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
val = +2.3346.
val = -23.346.
val = -0.0233.
val = +233.00.
```

Comment: This requires calculating needed number of decimal places manually in code.  what is the way to do this with code for any case?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I can come up with is as follows:

```
const char *format = "val = %+6.*f\n";
int places_past_decimal = ???;
printf(format, places_past_decimal, 2.334563f);
```

In this case, you will need to pass an additional argument (`places_past_decimal`) which is the number of digits remaining in the number that aren't used by the left side of the number.

Comment: I thought about it, but hoped for the best solution.